# How to open a pdf with WScript.Shell

Tags: javascript, shell, hta, wsh

I'm creating a HTA application that needs to open PDF document. I cannot assum that the user will have acrobat installed on his PC as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541870/open-pdf-at-specific-page-using-vbscript)

The WScript ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahcz2kh6(v=VS.85).aspx)) allow you to run a command line application. But what I would like, is for the WScript to simulate a double click on the file.

I would like to be able to do something like

```
var wshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
wshShell.Exec(pdfFilePath); // That does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is:

```
new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell").Run(pdfFile,1,false);
```

Answer (score 2):

In `cmd`, you can open a file like this: `start c:\path\to\file.pdf`

Maybe this works

```
wshShell.Exec("start " & pdfFilePath); //do you do string concat like this in wscript?
```

Comment: Sorry for this to work I would need to use something like : `wshShell.Run('cmd /C start '+pdfFile,1,false);`

Answer (score 2):

If pdfFile contains space, you must be add " and " into start and end of pdfFilePath
Change to: wshShell.Run('cmd /C start '+ '\"' + pdfFile + '\"' ,1,false)