# HTA page opening the program but not running the file

Tags: javascript, html, cmd, hta, wsh

After downloading all the lecture videos and other resources of a course,I wanted to make a course page for myself for easy access.

And I want the video open in VLC Player.

I tried the following code:

```
<html>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function RunFile() 
            {
                WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                WshShell.Run("vlc -vvv F:/Vishnu.mp4", 2, false);
            }
        </script>

<button onclick="RunFile()">Click Me!</button>

</html>
```

Here I took a test video file **Vishnu.mp4** in **F:** and tried opening it using an HTA page with the above mentioned code.

The problem is that the VLC Player opens but the file doesn't play.No error message is displayed.

After coming across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027698/how-to-open-a-pdf-with-wscript-shell) related question,I tried the **Exec** method.
But the same problem persists.VLC Player opens but the file doesn't play.And no error message are displayed.

I'm clueless about what went wrong.As per my understanding after reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) & [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the **strCommand** argument of the **Run** & **Exec** method must be the same string I would otherwise give in the command line to accomplish the task.

By the way,in case it's required:
1.My OS is Windows 7 Enterprise Ed
2.VLC Player version is 2.0.6 Twoflower

Any help is appreciated.

---

I tried embedding VLC player in the page.The file opens in the embedded player but keyboard shortcuts & other features like fast fwd,speeding up the video,equalizer etc don't work.

Is there any way to open the file in VLC Player.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that vlc is added to the system path variables by running the video directly from the Command Processor: `C:\>vlc -vvv F:/Vishnu.mp4`
Or only: `C:\>vlc` to try to launch VLC itself.

I don't have vlc added to system path, but then I used vlc's full path.

The following ran on my Windows 7 PC:

```
<html>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile() 
        {
            WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            the_file = '"C:/\Program Files/\VideoLAN/\VLC/\vlc.exe" -vvv "file:///D:/Green BAK/Video/Kurzweil-1.mp4"';
            alert(the_file);
            WshShell.Run(the_file, 2, false);
        }
    </script>

<button onclick="RunFile()">Click Me!</button>

</html>
```

Comment: :Sir,before trying the above mentioned query,I had added the required folder to the Path variable.

In fact,when I run the `C:\>vlc -vvv F:/Vishnu.mp4` command from cmd,the same problem occurs.VLC Player opens but the file doesn't play.

Comment: great, then just put your file name like in my answer: file:///f:/Vishnu.mp4 or f:/\Vishnu.mp4 your problem is with the file location reference. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.`f:/\Vishnu.mp4` doesn't work but `file:///f:/Vishnu.mp4` works perfectly.I guess `file:///<file_name>` is the syntax for specifying the filename.